# Problema PHP Mailer Version PHP 7.1

Tags: php, phpmailer

Buenas tengo este código y creo que me esta dando problemas por la versión de `php7` pero no consigo averiguar que pasa.

El formulario se envía correctamente menos si ponga el email, si pongo el email no me deja enviarlo ni se envía, si no pongo email se envía correctamente.

Dejo el código a ver si podéis echarme un cable.

```
require("class.phpmailer.php");
require("class.smtp.php");


$nombre = $_POST["name"];
$emailre = $_POST["email"];
$mensaje = $_POST["message"];


$destinatario = "info@XXXXXXXXXX.es";


$mail->Host = $smtpHost; 
$mail->Username = $smtpUsuario; 
$mail->Password = $smtpClave;


$mail->From = $emailre; // Email desde donde envio el correo.
$mail->FromName = $nombre;
$mail->AddAddress($destinatario); // Esta es la direccion a donde enviamos 
los datos del formulario

$mail->Subject = "Formulario desde el Sitio Web"; // Este es el titulo del 
email.
$mensajeHtml = nl2br($mensaje);

$mail->AltBody = "{$mensaje} \n\n "; // Texto sin formato HTML
// FIN - VALORES A MODIFICAR //

$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
)
);


$estadoEnvio = $mail->Send(); 
if($estadoEnvio){
echo "El correo fue enviado correctamente.";
exit();
} else {
echo "Ocurrio un error inesperado.";
exit();
}
```

Comment: Saludos cuando hablas de "email" a que te refieres con ello al del "destinatario" ó "emisor"...

Comment: emisor es cuando pongo en el formulartio el emial del emisor sea cual sea el del destino llega correcto.

Comment: Creo que tienes un error en tu codigo, el email que recibes del POST debe ser solo de manera informativa, ya que en realidad el correo lo esta enviando tu servidor, no lo esta enviando el dominio del usuario que pone su email en el formulario. por lo que al ponerlo en el FROM no coinciden los nombre de dominio. por eso es que cuando no lo pones el correo si se envia. Repito el $_POST['email'] lo podrias poner en el cuerpo del mensaje, algo como "Este mensaje te lo envio Juan y su correo es" $_POST['email'].

Comment: Saludos si es un formulario de sitio web como manifiestas deberia tener siempre el mismo emisor es decir no ser variado, lo que si debe cambiar seria el destinatario o quien recibe en este caso puede ser tanto el dueño del sitio web como el cliente o persona que llena el formulario .

Comment: el destinatario siempre es el mismo ya que soy quien lo recibo, lo que quiero que cambie es el correo del cliente que esta solicitando soporte en este caso o alguna pregunta quiero recibir el correo de ese usuario solamente.

Comment: No uses el email del solicitante como originador. Puedes ponerlo en un campo reply-to, o en el cuerpo del mensaje.

Answer (score 0):

Quiza esto te ayude amigo:
"En una pagina de soporte a seguimientos he diseñado un formulario sencillo de contacto que me envia un correo a los destinatarios que deseo, cuando el sistema les devuelve datos incorrectos"

/**Codigo de la pagina a la que se refencia el post del boton del formulario**/

```
<?php
$destino = "destinatario1@gmail.com" . ", ";
$destino .= "destinatario2@gmail.com" . ", ";
$destino .= "destinatario3@gmail.com";
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$identidad = $_POST["identidad"];
$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
$mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];
$contenido = "Nombre: " . $nombre . "\nCorreo: " . $correo . "\nTelefono: " . $telefono . "\nNumero identidad ingresado: " . $identidad . "\nMensaje: " .$mensaje;
mail($destino, "Verificar Identidad", $contenido ,$desde);
echo "
<script>
alert('Gracias $nombre tu mensaje ha sido enviado, pronto nos estaremos comunicando contigo.');
window.location= '../'
</script>";
header("location:gracias");
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Skipp, pero asi es como lo tenia antes, pero ahora uso un servidor SMTP y no puedo hacerlo asi tengo que usar la fucnion MailerPHP o alguna parecida para enviar el email de forma segura.